# maven write to version.txt and build

Tags: maven

I am 100% new to maven and need to perform the following actions.

Say I have a folder called *src/myfolder* which contains a file called *version.txt*

the contents of version.txt are:

`maj:1
min:0
incr:0
rev:123`

I want to increment the rev number to 124 and then compress *tgz *myfolder*.

How do I go about setting up a basic pom.xml and assembly descriptor xml to perform this and what would be the commands I would need to run to do this?

I'd be grateful for any help

Comment: What is the purpose of this file? For what do you need it? Why not adding a file into `src/main/resources` and activate filtering and use things like `${project.version}` in it ?

Comment: i need it because my next task is to ensure that the tar file that I create matches those numbers but I have tried to simplify my problem so I didn't ask that question.

Comment: If you create a tar.gz file via maven-assembly-plugin you can use [build-helper-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) to handle this including the increment see referenced page. So best is to have your project having the same version and use this ...as foundation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the incrementing is something that Maven will do out of the box, so you will need to run some custom code inside your Maven build. For such purposes, I tend to use the GMaven plugin (now it's the GMavenPlus plugin) to embed custom groovy code. Look at the [Example usage page](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki/Examples#execute-scripts) for inspiration.